# PDO Fetch and rowCount (PHP)

Tags: php, pdo, rowcount

```
try {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl4 WHERE tur=:tur AND link=:link";
  $res = $db -> prepare($sql);
  $res -> bindParam(":tur",$tur);
  $res -> bindParam(":link",$link);
  $res -> execute();
  $res = $res -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if($res->rowCount()!=0){
    echo 'OK';
  }else{
    echo "No!";
  }
}catch (Exception $e) {
   echo "Error5";
}
```

But the problem is I get that error

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\sf-19\pages\topic.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sf-19\index.php(18): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sf-19\pages\topic.php on line 19
```

If I delete if statement (has rowCount) everything works well. Yet I want to check if the query has result.

What am I missing? or what is the best way to check if query has result?
Thanks

Comment: Don't do this `$res = $res -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` maybe this `$rows = $res -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: That silly problem aside, you don't need this useless function at all. `if($res){` would be enough.

Comment: @YourCommonSense your advise worked. But I still don't understand why my code didn't work. Also I changed $res = $res -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); this line to $row = $res -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); still got error.

Comment: because you are calling a member function rowCount() on *array*.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
$res = $res -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

which is overwriting the value of `$res` before you use it in

```
if($res->rowCount()!=0){
```

You should probably use a different variable name for that value e.g.

```
$rows = $res -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I changed the variable name but still get error.

Comment: Yes you are right. I had changed wrong variable.